# How do I make realistic bounce angles when an object collides with arbitrary angles against walls and obstacles all at different angles?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, physics, collision

So I'm making a 2D puzzle/platformer game for Android/iOS in Flash CS6. HitTestObject is a great function - and I'm using it currently - but my problem is with the physics:

I want to take my arbitrary player object which has a velocity (in 2d vector form) and be able to bounce it off of arbitrary walls/obstacles/etc. which can be angled at arbitrary angles (eg. a wall say at 30 degrees below the y-axis somewhere in the middle of the screen). Now the player object can be traveling at arbitrary angle before colliding with it.

Now how I want to set this up is to have my obstacles built using Flash CS6's graphics tools and then be part of the overarching "Level" class which is stored in the library. There can be many obstacles all over the map at any point and any angle. I need to figure how to realistically bounce the player off a wall (we shall assume this is all in space and thus no friction or loss of momentum with the bounces) and get the correct angle. The player class should not know the dimensions of the obstacle class and all visual interactive game objects (like obstacles and player) inherit from a GameObject class (which has some basic movement characteristics for any visual objects).

I hope this all makes sense... anyway does anyone how to handle to this scenario?

Comment: How do you represent the angle of the wall? Suppose it's a floor canted 30 degrees clockwise. Is it `30`? Or `-30`? Or `60`? Or `(0.5, 0.86)`? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about a perfectly [inelastic collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision). If a sphere collides elastically against a flat wall, it retains the same speed, but the directional components of its velocity are all mirrored about the normal vector to the wall.

Comment: I understand about the inelastic collision concept. I could treat that part as vertical or horizontal wall and rotate it the angle the wall is.

But here is the real question: So let's assume this ball is in space (no friction and a vacuum) and it is bouncing off the walls normally. However there can be arbitrary shapes and obstacles all at different angles within this area. How would know which shape is which and where exactly is this ball bouncing off so I can make the normal? What about irregular shapes or more complex polygons (like stars, etc.)? What is they are all at different angles?